# Why don't methods need to return a value after throwing an exception?

Tags: java, exception, return

This is a contrived example. I have a non-void method and it throws an exception. Why don't I have to return a value afterwards? After all, the method is non-void.

```
public static Toast makeText(Context context, CharSequence text, int duration) {
    throw new RuntimeException("Stub!");
    //Must return something from here but there is not, Why?
}
```

Comment: The method always unconditionally ends with an exception. A method that ends with an exception has no return value, as it threw an exception. Id suggest you learn the basics of exceptions in Java and how to handle them.

Comment: Where do you use this method!

Comment: Hi. I would suggest you to google "how return statement in functions work". When you have basic idea, you should google "throwing and handling exceptions". There are tons of information on internet. Good luck!

Comment: Exceptions enter a special control flow and end the regular method control flow. The method is exit and Java traverses back the call-stack until it found a try-catch that catches this exception event. If none was found, the program is end. In particular, the method is **not continued** and since it doesnt end "normally", it also does not return any value.

Comment: @MetinBulak This class exists in Android

Comment: @Zabuzard Firstly thanks for editing the title because my title was unclear. I'll study exceptions in Java as you said because I don't remember I took something like this. Thanks.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Throwing an exception interrupts the flow of control, exiting from the method immediately. When an exception is thrown, no return value is needed because the code which *called* the method does not complete normally. For example, in the following code, there is no need for `foo` to return a number, because `int x = foo();` doesn't succeed, it instead propagates the exception:

```java
int foo() {
    throw new RuntimeException();
}
void bar() {
    int x = foo();
    // This line will not be reached
    System.out.println(x);
}
```

Since the code after `int x = foo();` won't be executed anyway, there is no need for `x` to receive a return value from `foo`, and therefore `foo` doesn't need to provide a return value.

In fact, a method cannot both return a value and also throw an exception, since returning a value would mean the method completes normally.

Comment: To add on that, imagine the author of `bar()` doesnt know that `foo()` can throw and imagine `bar()` would be non-void. If methods would need to return values after getting exceptions, how would he know that `int x = foo(); return x + 5;` is unsafe and doesnt reach the final line? It would be totally chaotic if you think this through.

Comment: @Zabuzard If, hypothetically, methods needed to return values even when they throw exceptions, then `int x = foo(); return x + 5;` would be fine; `x` would have a value because `foo` would have to have returned one. It would just mean that exceptions would have to not interrupt control flow. You could design a language like this; actually it is very similar to how errors are handled in C, where instead of throwing an exception to signal the error condition, you set an error flag and continue execution, assuming the caller will check for the error flag if they care whether an error occurred.

Comment: "since returning a value would mean the method completes normally" this is incorrect, or at least is using different terminology to the Java meaning of "completes normally": returning a value is considered abnormal completion.

Comment: @AndyTurner It means the method *invocation* would complete normally, i.e. the line `int x = foo();`. The `return` statement itself does not "complete normally" per the JLS, but the `return` statement is not the method.

Comment: @kaya3 then say the method invocation :)

Comment: @AndyTurner I don't think that is necessary, since what I wrote is not wrong from a technical standpoint anyway; if I wrote "returning a value would mean the method *body* completes normally" then that would be technically incorrect per the JLS. But returning and throwing are things which happen at runtime when a method is invoked, not compile-time properties of the method body, so in context I think it is clear enough what I am talking about.

Answer (score 5):

There is no actual requirement for a method returning a value to contain a return statement. Perhaps surprisingly, this code is legal:

```
int noReturn() {
  while (true) {}
}
```

The key big of the language spec is [JLS 8.4.7](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se14/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.4.7), which says:

> If a method is declared to have a return type (§8.4.5), then a compile-time error occurs if the body of the method can complete normally (§14.1).

"Normal completion" is described in [JLS 14.1](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se14/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.1):

> Every statement has a normal mode of execution in which certain computational steps are carried out. The following sections describe the normal mode of execution for each kind of statement.
>
> If all the steps are carried out as described, with no indication of abrupt completion, the statement is said to complete normally. However, certain events may prevent a statement from completing normally:
>
> - The break, yield, continue, and return statements (§14.15, §14.21, §14.16, §14.17) cause a transfer of control that may prevent normal completion of expressions, statements, and blocks that contain them.
> - Evaluation of certain expressions may throw exceptions from the Java Virtual Machine (§15.6). An explicit throw (§14.18) statement also results in an exception. An exception causes a transfer of control that may prevent normal completion of statements.

So: the requirement is that the method must not complete normally; and both `return` and `throw` are ways of causing the method to complete abnormally.

---

Note that this doesn't say that the method must complete abnormally instead: returning to the while loop example at the start, that doesn't complete normally or abnormally: because the loop condition is a constant true, and doesn't contain a return, throw or break, or a statement that might throw an exception, that loop never completes, which is also fine (at least from the language perspective).