# Throw exception instead of return. What is the actual type of method return?

Tags: java, url, return-type

I was digging behind the `openStream()` method from `URL` class in Java to find its actual type of return. From [OpenJDK](https://hg.openjdk.org/jdk8/jdk8/jdk/file/687fd7c7986d/src/share/classes/java/net/URL.java), its source is:

> ```
> public final InputStream openStream() throws java.io.IOException {
>     return openConnection().getInputStream();
> }
> ```

The return type is obviously an Object of `InputStream` which is an abstract class. So, this is the declared type, what is the actual type of return object?
I followed `openConnection()` method which returns an object of `URLConnection` class. I also followed its [source code](https://hg.openjdk.org/jdk8/jdk8/jdk/file/687fd7c7986d/src/share/classes/java/net/URLConnection.java) to find the return of `getInputSteam()`. Finally, I found this code:

> ```
> public InputStream getInputStream() throws IOException {
>     throw new UnknownServiceException("protocol doesn't support input");
> }
> ```

My question is what is the actual return type of `getInputStream()` which will be the actual return type of `openStream()`?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why don't methods need to return a value after throwing an exception?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70301081/why-dont-methods-need-to-return-a-value-after-throwing-an-exception)

Comment: `URLConnection` is also an abstract class. Keep looking.

Comment: @rgher Thank you. This gives a clue about the first question and I may dig more. But the second question is the main topic of this question. I will remove this part in order not to declared duplicate by community.

Comment: @user207421 this is also a good point, but I cannot dig more.

Comment: The actual type of the return depends on the concrete subclass of `URLConnection`. There isn’t a single answer.

Comment: For example, see [sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection#getInputStream()](https://github.com/openjdk/jdk/blob/1588dd934ce4e00a060e329b80f721d894559597/src/java.base/share/classes/sun/net/www/protocol/http/HttpURLConnection.java#L1596) to see the standard implementation used for `http` URLs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> *"... My question is what is the actual return type of `getInputStream()` which will be the actual return type of `openStream()`?"*

Here is an example using an *HTTPS* address.

Use a *debugging process*, and place a *break-point* on the *[URL#openStream](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.base/java/net/URL.html#openStream())* *method*.
And, I mean the actual method, and not your invocation.

From here, *"step into"* the *openConnection* method.
And then again, *"step into"* the *openConnection(URL)* method.

This brings you to the *sun.net.www.protocol.https.Handler* class.

Advance once more, to the *openConnection(URL, Proxy)* method, which returns a new instance of *sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl*.

Traversing further, you'll find that an instance of *[HttpsURLConnection](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.base/javax/net/ssl/HttpsURLConnection.html)* is returned, via the *sun.net.www.protocol.https.DelegateHttpsURLConnection* class.

Answer (score 3):

You know, I had (almost) this exact question when I was starting with Java years ago, except I was confused about `java.awt.Graphics`.

See [Programming to an interface](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/383947/what-does-it-mean-to-program-to-an-interface)

The idea is that you actually don't need to know the precise class - anything that implements the interface can be swapped in or out. This makes code more adaptable over time.